# In Spring Kafka, do I need to add the @EnableKafka annotation to my application if I'm just using producer?

Tags: spring-kafka

As per my understanding of the below documentation, it seems, @EnableKafka annotation might be required for consumers/listeners.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/EnableKafka.html

Does this mean, this annotation is applicable in the context of consumers but not producers? Please clarify.

Comment: I doubt it. Producer must be triggered by your some internally anyway. The annotation is required to create the beans that 'poll' kafka periodically.

Answer (score 1):

If you have doubts, it is better just to try that from your project and see how it is going.

Another way is to follow by its source code to analyze the logic behind that annotation. This way is easier for me because I'm too lazy to wait for build to fail when I'm not sure in the outcome. So, let's follow together!

```
@Import(KafkaListenerConfigurationSelector.class)
public @interface EnableKafka {
}
```

See that `KafkaListenerConfigurationSelector`. It says that for itself - `listener`. Since there is nothing about producer on this annotation, then no need in it when you have only a producer logic in your application.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.